# How to do regular expression to extract string from HTML file

Tags: python, html

I still cannot figure out how to extract links like this:

```
http: example.com/AA-HDCM-300B.pdf
```

Since I want to extract the product part number `"AA-HDCM-300B"` which begins with `"AA-"`.

Does anyone what the extraction code will be?

Comment: Please provide more examples of the links

Comment: http://www.idview.com/IDVIEW/Products/Cameras/Covert/assets/IV-PC229XP.pdf

Comment: So you want to extract `IV-PC229XP` from that link?

Comment: YES. Absolutely. Do you know how to write the extraction code? I tried, but always failed.

Comment: Is the pdf filename always be the product number?

Comment: Yes. Of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

url = 'dview.com/IDVIEW/Products/Cameras/Covert/assets/IV-PC229XP.pdf'
result = re.findall('(IV.*)\.', url)
```

Output:

```
IV-PC229XP
```

Comment: But if I have thousands of links from HTML, and some don't contain the part number? So that is the reason why I'd like to use re to extract the string begins with some certain words.

Comment: From what source you want to extract part number?

Comment: I did the web scraping and downloaded the html file for the links. Among those links I could see the product number. That is the reason why I would like to use re to extract product numbers from the html links.

Comment: Can you show examples of links which `don't contain the part number`?

Comment: url = 'http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer
http://www.idview.com/IDVIEW/products/Cameras/UltraHD/Ultra_HD_Solution.html/IDVIEW-home.html

Comment: So you want to skip that links?

Comment: Yes. I only want to extract the part number.

Comment: So basically you need to find all links to PDF files?

Comment: Actually I have already had all the links. Among those links some are useless, some link names contain the part number. So I just want to extract those part numbers.

Comment: How to distinguish part number from useless links?

Comment: Since part numbers are all begin with IV-, so only strings begin with IV- will be extracted.